Visual Studio - Is there an Option to keep Output Window in foreground?
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.8.6
Is there an option in Visual Studio to keep the Output window in the foreground and NOT switch to the Error Window unless there is an error?
It is mighty annoying to have to manually switch to the Output window every single time I do a build.

All windows in Visual Studio are dockable. You can arrange them however you like and give the output window it's own space.

Note the pin icon in the upper right corner.  Click the down arrow next to it and select "Float".

In Visual Studio, there isn't a built-in option to pin the Output window (or any other tool window) to always stay in the foreground. You can dock the Output window to one of the sides of your workspace. This way, it remains part of your main Visual Studio window layout.

So, to remedy this situation, I moved the Error Window to another monitor. Kind of stupid to not allow you to "hide" it but this works
